# Problem with Data Insertion using SQLAlchemy and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a simple app to record my working hours. I'm using SQLAlchemy and the SQLite as the database. Here's my `model.py`:

```
from infra.base import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Float, ForeignKey


# class TaskFact - main table
class TaskFact(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'task_fact'
    task_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    task_date = Column(String)
    task_description = Column(String)
    task_hours = Column(Float)
    is_ccr = Column(Integer)
    project_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('project_dim.project_id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.date} - {self.task_description} - {self.project_code_fk}'

# class ProjectDim - project dimension table
class ProjectDim(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'project_dim'
    project_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    project_alias = Column(String, nullable=False)
    project_official_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    project_category = Column(String, nullable=True)
    project_corporate_segment = Column(String, nullable=True)
    tasks = relationship('TaskFact', backref='tasks')
```

And I have a class that does the insertion in the TaskFact table:

```
from .models import *
from infra.database_factory import DatabaseFactory

class TaskFactRepository:

    def insert_new_task(self,
                        date: str,
                        description: str,
                        hour: float,
                        is_ccr: str,
                        project_code_fk: str) -> None:
        """
        inserts a new task in the task table

        :param date: date of the task
        :type date: str
        :param description: description of the task
        :type description: str
        :param hour: time spent in the task
        :type hour: float
        :param is_ccr: indication if the activity is CCR
        :type is_ccr: str
        :param project_code_fk: code of the project related to task
        :type project_code_fk: str
        """
        with DatabaseFactory() as db:
            try:
                data = TaskFact(
                    task_date=date,
                    task_description=description,
                    task_hours=hour,
                    is_ccr=is_ccr,
                    project_id=project_code_fk
                )
                db.session.add(data)
                db.session.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                db.session.rollback()
                raise e
```

But when I try to execute the following test, it raises a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table task_fact has no column named project_id`. That's the script I'm running (I'll erase the info to preserve confidentiality):

```
from repository.task_fact_repository import TaskFactRepository
from repository.project_repository import ProjectDimensionRepository

# create repo object
db_proj = ProjectDimensionRepository()
db_task = TaskFactRepository()


# test task insertion
db_task.insert_new_task(
    date='2023-01-03',
    description='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    hour=9.5,
    is_ccr='True',
    project_code_fk='XXXXXXXXX'
)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is your database up to date with your models? Do you use migrations?

Comment: Hey Yurii, this was exactly the problem. I had a column with a typo and thus, was not able to write data in it. Thanks !